# Getting 502 bad gateway when connecting to my SignalR webapp while app insights is on

Tags: signalr, azure-application-insights, azure-web-app-service

I have a SignalR .NetCore Azure Web App with a Typescript front end. The site and SignalR launch and show the socket connection connect fine. But I've got some issue and I need to turn on App Insights so I can debug.

When I turn app insights on I then get 502 Bad Gateway. I have no idea why and can't find a solution anywhere.

[image: Here is the console with App Insights off]

[image: Here is the console with App Insights On]